# Filter a range of dates from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, date-range

Im reading a .txt file which I've split into an array with lines of info.

This is my original .txt

```
|datestamp              |endpoint    |id    |
|2019-03-01 09:00:00UTC |/co.html    |12345 |
|2019-03-01 09:00:00UTC |/co.html    |12346 |
|2019-03-01 10:00:00UTC |/co.html    |12345 |
|2019-03-01 10:30:00UTC |/hello.html |12347 |
|2019-03-01 11:00:00UTC |/co.html    |12347 |
|2019-03-02 11:00:00UTC |/co.html    |12348 |
|2019-03-02 12:00:00UTC |/hello.html |12348 |
|2019-03-03 13:00:00UTC |/hello.html |12349 |
```

so now I've got this array of info:

```
[
'|datestamp              |endpoint    |id    |',
'|2019-03-01 09:00:00UTC |/co.html    |12345 |',
'|2019-03-01 09:00:00UTC |/co.html    |12346 |',
'|2019-03-01 10:00:00UTC |/co.html    |12345 |',
'|2019-03-01 10:30:00UTC |/hello.html |12347 |',
'|2019-03-01 11:00:00UTC |/co.html    |12347 |',
'|2019-03-02 11:00:00UTC |/co.html    |12348 |',
'|2019-03-02 12:00:00UTC |/hello.html |12348 |',
'|2019-03-03 13:00:00UTC |/hello.html |12349 |',
''
]
```

So I need to filter on say these datestamps
2019-03-01 10:00:00UTC - 2019-03-02 11:00:00UTC

Do I need to split the array by the pine "|"  as well before doing that?

How can I solve this?

Comment: Yes, split each line by `|`.

Comment: Thanks @IslamElshobokshy for your respons, thats what I though as well, but then ADT showed another version of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need to split the array's elements first.  You could create Date() objects out of part of the strings and compare these to Date() objects representing your start and end date/times:

```js
let mydates = [
'|datestamp              |endpoint    |id    |',
'|2019-03-01 09:00:00UTC |/co.html    |12345 |',
'|2019-03-01 09:00:00UTC |/co.html    |12346 |',
'|2019-03-01 10:00:00UTC |/co.html    |12345 |',
'|2019-03-01 10:30:00UTC |/hello.html |12347 |',
'|2019-03-01 11:00:00UTC |/co.html    |12347 |',
'|2019-03-02 11:00:00UTC |/co.html    |12348 |',
'|2019-03-02 12:00:00UTC |/hello.html |12348 |',
'|2019-03-03 13:00:00UTC |/hello.html |12349 |',
''
]

let startDate = new Date("2019-03-01 10:00:00");
let endDate = new Date("2019-03-02 11:00:00");

let filtered = mydates.filter(d => new Date(d.substr(1, 19)) >= startDate && new Date(d.substr(1, 19)) <= endDate);
console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: Thanks @ADT, that was neat and easy to understand!

Answer (score 0):

please try it.

```js
let res = [
'|datestamp              |endpoint    |id    |',
'|2019-03-01 09:00:00UTC |/co.html    |12345 |',
'|2019-03-01 09:00:00UTC |/co.html    |12346 |',
'|2019-03-01 10:00:00UTC |/co.html    |12345 |',
'|2019-03-01 10:30:00UTC |/hello.html |12347 |',
'|2019-03-01 11:00:00UTC |/co.html    |12347 |',
'|2019-03-02 11:00:00UTC |/co.html    |12348 |',
'|2019-03-02 12:00:00UTC |/hello.html |12348 |',
'|2019-03-03 13:00:00UTC |/hello.html |12349 |',
''
]
let dates = [];
for(let i=1;i<res.length-1;i++)
{
  let splitedItem = res[i].split('|');
  dates.push(new Date(splitedItem[1].replace("UTC","").trim()));
}
console.log(dates)
```

now you have an array of dates and you can query to this array with lambda expression.

Comment: Thanks for your respons! I will look into lambda expressions, haven't heard of that yet.

Comment: Whilst that will produce an array of dates, you have now disassociated the rest of the string content from the date.  I assume that the purpose of the filtering is to also identify the "endpoint" and "id" values associated with those dates.